# Android Studio Error when trying to UPDATE my SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been following a tutorial online to implement a database into my Android Studio Application Project. However i have used the same code but keep getting the same error below every time a run the emulator and try to update one of my records: **UNFORTUNETLY THE PROJECT HAS STOP RUNNING**

I have checked my logcat and the following appears:

> beginning of crash 04-04 20:25:23.290
>   4019-4019/com.example.mark.messaround2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.mark.messaround2, PID: 4019
>                                                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ID (code 1):
>   , while compiling: UPDATE DAY_TABLE SET NAME=?,ID=?,MARKS=?,SURNAME=?
>   WHERE ID = ?
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1577)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.mark.AutismApplicationSuite.DatabaseHelper.updateData(DatabaseHelper.java:75)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.mark.AutismApplicationSuite.ChooseDayScreen$9.onClick(ChooseDayScreen.java:152)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Please post the code from your SQLiteOpenHelper class

Comment: Wont let me post it... dont understand the indent you must do.... as i have indented it FOUR SPACES but wont let me post

Comment: @MarkWilliamson https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Check this two, any of them can work for you.

1. In "DAY_TABLE", you didn't make any attribute for "ID". So make a attribute named 
   "ID" and update the version of DB
2. You didn't update the version of DB after changing "DAY_TABLE".